# Send messages to Client with C# using openfire server

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

Our firm is using message API's to send various alerts to our clients. As the charges are getting high for message API's we are planning to have WhatsApp sort of thing(An Android chat client) on our customer's phone and send messages to them through OpenFire server.

I am new to this. I searched over Internet and found [jabber.net](https://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/wiki/GettingStarted) but the documentation didn't help me much to get started.

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34300/Google-Chat-Desktop-Application-using-Jabber-Net) on CodeProject but this is made to connect to GMail (though it is not even connecting to GMail). I tried changing the server to my PC's static IP but it didnt connect to it.

Please note that I am able to connect to OpenFire through Clients like jabiru(Android), Jabber(Android) and Spark(Windows Client) and chat with them. So no problem in server setting.

How should I start about with it.. How can I send messages to various clients on the basis of their username. Sorry for asking a foolish question but I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you can find a list of XMPP libraries for c# .NET:
http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/

All libraries listed there come with documentation and example, also jabber-net. The examples show you how to login and send messages. They should work out of the box with your Openfire server.

Comment: can you show me the link to login and send messages using jabber.net? I am not able to find it..

Comment: I am not looking for any paid library.. jabber.net is the only free library with no documentation at all.. :/

Comment: download it from here: https://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/
There are example included